Finding the radius of convergence of $\sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty \frac{(n!)^{k+4}}{((k+4)n)!}x^n$ for $k\in\mathbb N_+$
So I've been stuck on this homework problem for quite some time:

If $k$ is a positive integer, find the radius of convergence of the series
$$
\sum_{n = 0}^\infty \frac{(n!)^{k+4}}{((k+4)n)!}x^n
$$

I've tried using the ratio test to solve this, but for some reason, I got a wrong answer
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right| = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{((n+1)!)^{k+4}x^{n+1}}{((k+4)(n+1))!} \frac{((k+4)n)!}{(n!)^{k+4}x^n} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{(n+1)^{k+4}}{(k+4)(n+1)}
$$
Since degree of numerator > degree of denominator, this limit is divergent for all $x$, so radius of convergence $R = 0$. However, the autograder didn't recognize this as the right answer. And I'm so confused why.

The denominator is wrong. Besides use the symbol  $l=k+4,$ then the expressions simplify.

@RyszardSzwarc why is it wrong? can you elaborate more?

The d'Alembert ratio test is convenient as there are factorials involved. Let $l=k+4$ and $a_n$ denote the coefficient of $x^n.$ Then
$${a_{n+1}\over a_n}={(n+1)^l }{(ln)!\over (ln+l)!}={(n+1)^l\over (ln+1)(ln+2)\ldots (ln+l) }\\ ={(1+{1\over n})^l\over l^l(1+{1\over nl})(1+{2\over n^l})\ldots (1+{l\over nl})}\underset{n\to \infty}{\longrightarrow}{1\over l^l}$$ Therefore the radius of convergence is equal $l^l=(k+4)^{k+4}.$
If we apply the ratio test to the terms of the series, not just the coefficients, the limit will become $|x|/l^l.$
